# Mule - Object to parameters in Database

Tags: database, class, parameters, mule, workflow

I have this `mule flow`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:db="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db" xmlns:json="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.5.2"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json/current/mule-json.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db/current/mule-db.xsd">

    <spring:beans>

        <spring:bean id="propertyConfigurer"
            class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
            <spring:property name="locations">
                <spring:list>
                    <spring:value>configSQL.properties</spring:value>
                </spring:list>
            </spring:property>
        </spring:bean>

    </spring:beans>

    <db:generic-config name="BBDD_USER"  doc:name="Generic Database Configuration" driverClassName="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver" 
    url="${sql.url}/${sql.database};user=${sql.username};password=${sql.password}"/>

    <flow name="sincro-sql" doc:name="sincro-sql">

        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" host="localhost" port="8042" doc:name="HTTP"/>

        <logger message="#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" level="INFO" doc:name="JSON"/>

        <json:json-to-object-transformer doc:name="JSON to Object" returnClass="json.database.object.Data"/>

        <db:stored-procedure config-ref="BBDD_USER" doc:name="Data" source="json.database.object.Data" streaming="true">
            <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[{ CALL dbo.ExecSQL(:table_name, :field_name) }]]></db:parameterized-query>
            <db:in-param name="field_name" type="VARCHAR" value="field_test"/>
            <db:in-param name="table_name" type="VARCHAR" value="table_test"/>
        </db:stored-procedure>

    </flow>
</mule>
```

It **receives a JSON** that I **transform to object** with a **class** that contains:

```
@JsonAutoDetect    
public class Data{

        private String table_name;
        private String field_name;

        public void setTableName(String table_name) {
            this.table_name= table_name;
        }

        public String getTableName() {
            return table_name;
        }

        public void setFieldName(String field_name) {
            this.field_name= field_name;
        }

        public String getFieldName() {
            return field_name;
        }
    }
```

And finally, I call to my database. How can I **assign**, for example, the **property** about the table name **from the class** **to the parameter** in the **database** element?

For example,

```
<db:in-param name="table_name" type="VARCHAR" value="PROPERTY OF CLASS"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MEL(Mule Expression Langauge) and standard Java method invocation. As Data is you payload, use #[payload.table_name] MEL will automatically use the getter for that field.

Comment: Thanks !if it is an array, what should I use?

Comment: well if you want a specific item in the array, you can access it by index: #[payload[0].table_name]

Comment: Sorry, I posted a new answer to explain with more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33892365/mule-object-from-array-to-parameter-in-database Thanks